# AS3, using an Integer variable in an object path

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, integer

Is it possible to use an integer in a variable path?

I have up to 50+ corresponding instances to target depending on the current frame, and don't wish to write everything out 50+ times. Tracing the string + integer, and it comes back as the instance name every time, however using it as a path, although the Test Movie will launch,triggering the function produces "TypeError: Error #1123: Filter operator not supported on type".

```
var curFRAME:int;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,frame_dep);
function frame_dep(event:Event):void
{
trace("Cont_mclp_" + curFRAME);
this.("Cont_mclp_" + curFRAME).nextFrame();
}
```

Is it possible to use a integer variable in a path name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the square brackets notation `[]`:

```
this["Cont_mclp_" + curFRAME].nextFrame();
```